# get_template_part() not working with Advanced Custom Fields plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I work on the WordPress project I created testimonials in a special file called testimonials.php and I called the file on the page about us by get_template_part and it works fine but when I called (testimonials.php) to the home page  not show all parts of the input.

Use the Advanced Custom Fields plugin

This code

```
<!-- Start Section Testimonials -->
<section class="testimonials section-padding">
    <div class="carousel-right col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
        <div class="owl-carousel">
            <?php $testimonials = array ('post_type' => 'Testimonials' , 'order' => 'ASC');
                $query = new wp_query($testimonials);
                    if ($query->have_posts()) {
                    while ($query->have_posts()){
                        $query->the_post(); ?>
                            <!-- Start Item 1 -->
                            <div class="testimonials-item">
                                <!-- Testimonials Text -->
                                <div class="testimonials-text-item">
                                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Testimonials Title -->
                                <div class="testimonials-title clearfix">
                                    <!-- Title Img -->
                                    <div class="title-img">
                                        <img src="<?php the_field('image'); ?>" alt="testimonials">
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Title Text -->
                                    <div class="title-text">
                                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                        <p><?php the_field('small_title'); ?></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- End Item 1 -->
                        <?php }} ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <!-- Start Title -->
    <?php $testimonials = get_field('testimonials'); ?>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-md-5 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                <div class="testimonials-text clearfix">
                    <div class="title">
                        <span><?php echo $testimonials['small_title']; ?></span>
                        <h2><?php echo $testimonials['main_title']; ?></h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-p">
                    <?php echo $testimonials['description']; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Title -->
</section>
```

The part that does not appear from 
All inputs

```
<span> <? php echo $ testimonials ['small_title']; ?> </ span>
<h2> <? php echo $ testimonials ['main_title']; ?> </ h2>
<? php echo $ testimonials ['description']; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you used this in the single page it's working well and if you need it working in homepage you need to add the page id in ACF function like

```
$testimonials = get_field('testimonials',the_ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

**1 - Based to your codes get_field('testimonials') needs to be an array, so the best way is to give default values array to this function like :**

```
$testimonials = get_field('testimonials', array(
    'small_title' => '',
    'main_title' => '',
    'description' => ''
));
```

So by this way you set the default values if if the field is not array or null, beceause some times this function will return null if there no data recorded in the database for current post.

**2 - The following strings is getting the array $testimonials value by given key :**

```
echo $testimonials['small_title'];
echo $testimonials['main_title'];
echo $testimonials['description'];
```

But what about if the key is not exists in array $testimonials ?
you will need to use the PHP function [isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) with shorthand Conditional **if** statement to avoid warning message or breaking html codes.

**This is the right way :**

```
echo isset($testimonials['small_title']) ? $testimonials['small_title'] : '';
echo isset($testimonials['main_title']) ? $testimonials['main_title'] : '';
echo isset($testimonials['description']) ? $testimonials['description'] : '';
```

I hope this will help you to fix the problem

Comment: thank you for your reply
What do I put here, sorry for the question I am a beginner in Wordpress and my knowledge is simple in PHP
      $ testimonials = get_field ('testimonials', array (
            'small_title' => 'Here',
            'main_title' => 'Here',
            'description' => 'Here'
     ));

Comment: you can leave it empty or use default title to replace empty values